# Converting Image using pngdata causes app to freeze then crash

Tags: swift, uiimage

I'm using the following code to convert images to data to store them in core data, however its causing the app to crash due to running out of memory. The app is also frozen until the code completes

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Project> = Project.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        do {
            let results = try self.appData.moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            for project in results {
                NSLog("Project Name: \(String(describing: project.name))")
                if let mainPic = project.mainPicture {
                    if let mainPicName = mainPic.pictureName {
                        let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(mainPicName)
                        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePath) {
                            if let image : UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
                                let imageData = image.pngData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
        self.appData.saveContext()
        NSLog("13 Ran")
    }
```

If I comment out the let imageData = image.pngData() line then I don't get the issue

With the line commented out, the memory usage once the app has loaded is less than 100MB, if its not commented it gets to 1.15GB before going back to about 150MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this's a memory issue, I think.

How many project are fetched?

And you can change the code to:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Project> = Project.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    do {
        let results = try self.appData.moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let fileManager = FileManager.default


        for project in results {
            autoreleasepool {
            NSLog("Project Name: \(String(describing: project.name))")
            if let mainPic = project.mainPicture {
                if let mainPicName = mainPic.pictureName {
                    let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(mainPicName)
                    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePath) {
                        if let image : UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
                            let imageData = image.pngData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
    self.appData.saveContext()
    NSLog("13 Ran")
}
```

I think it should be fine.

Comment: Theres a total of 140 projects currently. Each project has a main image, and an infinite number of additional images. Your code doesn't compile, gives Use of unresolved identifier 'project'

Comment: its still using over 2GB and crashing. The interface is frozen while its running

Comment: what is the contents of mainPicture object? does it has any binary data field ?

Comment: Its a Picture entity from core data, with fields - dateTaken (Date), pictureData (Data), pictureName (String) and a relationship to the project entity. pictureData in=sn't in use yet, that's where I want to store imageData to sync the images with other devices

Comment: could you try to call self.appData.moc.refreshAllObjects() after at the end of each for loop?
It's weird, I think autoreleasepool on each for loop is enough

Comment: would that make a difference at this point? I'm not actually modifying them in the code yet

Comment: did you try to wrap each for loop in the autoreleasepool as I suggested?

Comment: do you mean move the autorelease to before the for loop then yes. Once it gets to the let imageData = image.pngData() line the memory usage goes up continuously

Comment: no, it should be in the for loop. And for more accurate, you can try to wrap only line `let imageData = image.pngData()` in the autoreleasepool

Comment: ok, that seems to have stopped the memory issue, it didn't go above 200MB, the ui is still frozen until it completes

Comment: I can switch the dispatch queue to DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { but its so much slower

Comment: You can change qos to higher priority to speed up it. And actually I asked you to wrap it in an auto release pool to test and make sure it’s an issue about memory. You shouldn’t call autorelease pool on each for loop, it’s head a overhead. You should split your loop then wrap them to autorelease pool. For example for each 20 projects in a autorelease pool. To determine which number should be used, you have to try to find out what number is best choice.

Comment: that's fine, it gives me a starting point for working that out as its now not crashing before its loaded